# JavaFX Scene Builder Refresh from Code

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to refesh Scene Builder's display after directly editing the FXML code-behind  ?

I don't like the idea of relying totally on a graphic code-generating helper and I like to keep full control on my code. So far I have to restart Scene Builder every time I tweak the code directly from Eclipse's code editor.

Otherwise there is no real integration to Eclipse; unlike what is advertised, it would just be and external standalone editor to generate code and that's it.

Comment: Do you save your changes after modifying the FXML file in Eclipse?

Comment: In Netbeans, if I press control-s in the FXML file, Scene Builder updates automatically.

Comment: have you tried following [this way](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-eclipse.htm) to see if it helps, other wise as mentioned, whenever I make a change I save it and it updates in my IDE

Comment: Once you saved the file in your IDE, click File > Revert to Saved. It will automatically revert to the saved version in your IDE. (for me it didn't update automatically)